# zsh not updating vcs_info

Tags: terminal, command-prompt, zsh

I'm just trying to show the current branch of the git repository I'm inside (if available) by using `vcs_info`. The relevant portion of my `.zshrc` file is as follows:

```
autoload -Uz vcs_info
zstyle ':vcs_info:*' enable git
zstyle ':vcs_info:*' formats "%F{010}(%b)%f "

precmd() { vcs_info }
setopt prompt_subst

PROMPT="%F{226}%m:%n @ %F{214}%1d %F{226}\$%f ${vcs_info_msg_0_}"
```

#### I expect:

1. I load the terminal and start at `~` (the home directory). zsh prompt should read

   `hostname:username @ user $`
2. `cd dev/repo` takes me into a git repo, zsh prompt should read

   `hostname:username @ repo $ (master)`
3. `cd ..` takes me back to `dev`, which isn't a git repo, prompt should read

   `hostname:username @ dev $`

#### I experience:

The prompt never changes / updates automatically; I have to run `source ~/.zshrc` to make the prompt update as I change directories.

#### What I have tried:

I've tried updating the `precmd()` block to be as follows:

```
precmd() {
    vcs_info
    echo "This has been executed"
}
```

And I see `This has been executed` right before every prompt, so I know that the precmd block is being entered correctly. It seems that the `vcs_info` just isn't working.

Perhaps I'm missing something; can someone point out what the issue could be? Thanks!

Comment: I ended up putting the PROMPT assignment inside the `precmd` method

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Figured it out by happenstance a few months later after not really caring... the prompt has to use single quotes instead of double-quotes.

`PROMPT='%F{226}%m:%n @ %F{214}%1d %F{226}\$%f ${vcs_info_msg_0_}'`

Comment: That is it! double-quotes now are buggy.
Thank you, you saved my day.

Comment: With single quotes I see a literal "${vcs_info_msg_0_}" in the prompt.

Comment: @CrisLuengo -  make sure you have prompt substitutions enabled with `setopt prompt_subst`

Comment: For me it's the other way around, double quotes are not working and just printing `${vcs_info_msg_0_}` as plain-text while double-quotes work but don't update the branch name

Comment: @RaulRene I got the same behavior

Answer (score 3):

Putting the whole thing inside the precmd() worked

```
autoload -Uz vcs_info
precmd() {
  vcs_info
  # Format the vcs_info_msg_0_ variable
  zstyle ":vcs_info:git:*" formats "(%b) "

  echo -e -n "\x1b[\x33 q"
  PROMPT="%B%1~ $%b %F{004}${vcs_info_msg_0_}%f> "
  RPROMPT=" %F{005}%T%f"
}
```

Comment: Regarding single vs double quotes. Single quotes had been working the previous day for me while they didn't worked anymore the next. 

Not sure what is the root cause behind that part of the bug, but the behavior seems fairly inconsistent when reading other comments in this question. I hope someone improves this question with an answer addressing that.

Comment: Quotes made no difference for me, but putting the variables in the precmd worked perfectly, thanks.